# embed tag for flash and w3c

Tags: html, flash, object, embed, w3c-validation

when validating a site using w3c validator it tells me the embed tag is not valid markup. So i take it out and it works on safari/chrome but not firefox(3.5.x) but validates fine. Is there something in the object tag i must add in order for firefox to display flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A List Apart* has a great article on that topic: [Flash Satay: Embedding Flash While Supporting Standards](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay).

Read that to understand the general difficulties with embedding flash and to read about different approaches to embed it in valid HTML. **And then** go and use [SWFobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed Flash as that is the best way to do it while having both standards support *and* browser compiliance.

In addition to that you *may* use the normal Flash Satay method to embed it for people without JavaScript.

Comment: The actual reasearch behind Flash Satay still applies in the same way, so no, it's not out of date. The only new thing is the caged method, which I would not really call a clean way either. And the static method of SWFobject still uses JavaScript to fix the last problems.

Comment: Wish I could edit that comment, but apparently I can only delete & repost - apparently I hadn't had my coffee when I wrote that and it makes no sense. 

The flash satay method that you're referencing is from 2002 and isn't supported in HTML5. But I suppose if you're trying to get your content to that tiny percentage of people who have flash enabled but not javascript, then yes, the satay method is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

embed has never been part of the HTML spec and object should be used. It's been so long since I've touched flash, I hesitate to say more than that which I know.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). It's valid, although I think I've had the validator trip up on it before (the w3 validator has been known to trip up on stuff like this on occasion).

Comment: um, did someone just go through and downvote every answer this page? lame.